# R dataframe: Transfrom values on multiple rows into list

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to transform this:

```
library(tibble)
(
  tribble(
    ~id, ~value,
## -----|--------| 
     1,   "qwer",
     1,   "asdf",
     2,   "uiop",
     3,   "zxcv",
     3,   "qwer",
     3,   "uiop" )
) -> input
```

into this:

```
(
  tribble(
    ~id,          ~values,
## -----|------------------------------| 
     1,   list("qwer", "asdf"),
     2,   list("uiop"),
     3,   list("zxcv", "qwer", "uiop"))
) -> output
```

Please note that the number of disinct values is not known...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit in view of comment below**

If you want to store each value as list containing every value as distinct item, please do it like this

```
input %>% group_by(dummy = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(value = list(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(value = list(value))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id value     
  <dbl> <list>    
1     1 <list [2]>
2     2 <list [1]>
3     3 <list [3]>

#check its structure
output <- input %>% group_by(dummy = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(value = list(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(value = list(value))

output$value[[1]]
[[1]]
[1] "qwer"

[[2]]
[1] "asdf"

#OR
output$value
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "qwer"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "asdf"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "uiop"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "zxcv"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "qwer"

[[3]][[3]]
[1] "uiop"
```

[image]

**old answer** this will store item in a vector first and then in a list (single item)

Use this

```
input %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(value = list(value))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id value    
  <dbl> <list>   
1     1 <chr [2]>
2     2 <chr [1]>
3     3 <chr [3]>

#check its items

output <- input %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(value = list(value))

output$value[[1]]
[1] "qwer" "asdf"

#OR
output$value
[[1]]
[1] "qwer" "asdf"

[[2]]
[1] "uiop"

[[3]]
[1] "zxcv" "qwer" "uiop"
```

sample data output is as under (which matches first syntax) still second one is suggested unless any specific reason to do so.

```
output$value
(
  tribble(
    ~id,          ~values,
    ## -----|------------------------------| 
    1,   list("qwer", "asdf"),
    2,   list("uiop"),
    3,   list("zxcv", "qwer", "uiop"))
) -> output

output$values

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "qwer"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "asdf"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "uiop"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "zxcv"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "qwer"

[[3]][[3]]
[1] "uiop"
```

[image]

Comment: I do not know why I have not even thought about `group_by` in this situation. Nevertheless, you do not obtain lists but vectors, even if you use `list`. Why is that?

Comment: It is indeed a list col. See that <list> has been written beneath value in output.  Criteria was a single item list

Comment: Or do you wanted to store each element as a separate item in the list??

Comment: It is different from the expected output I have specified in the orginal post.

Comment: check edited answer.  Whichever way you desire.  Good Luck

Comment: You are right my first expect was useless. But I am very happy to have learn the tricks you did to acheive it. I was not aware that `group_by` can create a variable...

Comment: Actually, when any new variable is created for sole purpose of grouping the data, it can be directly created inside a group_by statement, which saves an extra line of code.  Glad that it helped.  Hope you have already upvoted the answer.  Thanks.